# elements to attribute with custom logic not working

Tags: java, xml, xslt

while converting the element to attributes I am checking the name of parent element whether it present in element which we tried to convert as attribute.

Example like **planet_name** is the element and it contains the parent element (planet) so need to covert this as attribute otherwise as-is.

I wrote the xslt but its not working can any one please help on this?. Thanks in advance.

Sample XML Example:

```
<world>
            <planet>
               <planet_name>solaris</plante_name>
               <planet_number>23</plante_number>
               <test>value1</test>
             </planet>
</world>
```

Expected Output:

```
<world>
            <planet planet_name="solaris" planet_number="23">
               <test>value1</test>
             </planet>
</world>
```

XSLT as below

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!--Identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Match elements that contain children elements that don't contain children 
        elements themselves. -->
    <xsl:template match="*[*[not(*)]]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:variable name="attrName" select="name()" />
                <xsl:variable name="parentName" select="name(..)" />
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(normalize-space($parentName),normalize-space($attrName))">
                        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                           <xsl:value-of select="$parentName" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Do you have at least a well-formed input sample so that any XSLT we suggest has any chance to process the input?

Comment: <world>
 <planet>
  <planet_name>solaris</planet_name>
  <planet_number>23</planet_number>
  <test>value1</test>
 </planet>
</world>

Comment: Added the sample well formed XML. can you please help if any mistake is there in the xslt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(name(), name(current()))]" mode="attr"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(starts-with(name(), name(current())))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="attr">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. while converting to attribute want to remove parent element name so writing this line <xsl:attribute name="substring-after(name(),'_')">. Is this enough.. need string after underscore(_)

Comment: @Bablu This is not shown in your expected output. If you want, you could use `substring-after(name(), '_')` (at least in the given example).

Comment: I used but it was not working and snippet is  `<xsl:attribute name="substring-after(name(), '_')">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>`

Comment: You need to to keep the curly brackets around the expression.

Comment: Is there any possibility to avoid converting few elements to attributes. like element name equals to planet_number that no need of converting to attribute?.

Comment: Yes, you could add a condition such as `not(self::planet_number)`.

Comment: can you pls help how to skip multiple element like that?.

Comment: after adding the condition element is skipping from attribute and even from output also.

Comment: @Bablu I suggest you post a new question.